# Powershell degree symbol

Tags: powershell

Using powershell_ISE and SQL server 2012.

I run a PowerShell script to generate an email and I want to include the degree symbol within it (°) but PowerShell substitutes it with a question mark (?).

If I use the code below I get a question mark within the email

```
$value = [string]([math]::Round($row.value, 2)) + " °C"
```

If I use the degree symbol in the `HTML` mark-up for the email I get a question mark.

```
$emailDetails += "<td class=TableContent style='width: 100px; padding:5px;' align=center>$value" + " °C" + " </td>"
```

If I change the value from the original SQL query to

```
select tagname, (convert(NVARCHAR, ROUND(value, 2)) + '°C') as value, [description] from @t
```

guess what.... I still get a question mark when I output it to an email.

I am typing in the degree symbol using Alt + 248.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

The answer is as follows.

```
$emailDetails += "<td class=TableContent style='width: 100px; padding:5px;' align=center>$value&#176</td>"
```

The 176 part of `&#176` was found by selecting Arial from the character map and changing the Hex result to decimal.  As this is for an internal system where I know the default font for the email system this will work.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'm not all that familar with porwershell but in html (which it looks like you're able to use in your case) you can type a degree symbol with `&deg;`. The question mark is showing up because powershell is having trouble recognizing the encoding of the degree symbol.

`$emailDetails += "<td class=TableContent style='width: 100px; padding:5px;' align=center>$value &deg;C </td>"`

Comment: »The question mark is showing up because powershell is having trouble recognizing the encoding of the degree symbol.« The question mark is a sign that they messed up with encodings along the way. That's a fundamental trait of developers, the languages are not at fault here.